# Portable paths and PHP CLI

Tags: path, php

So I got burned again by forgetting that the CLI does not have $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] defined.

What is the best way to get a portable/relative path in a PHP script that will be run by cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean such as:

```
  $thePath= dirname(__FILE__);
```

Comment: indeed, it will yield the same result as long as you are using php 5.3 and up. For compatibility reasons though, it is better to use `dirname(__FILE__)` as it always works.